# Get Netflix video duration on safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using `videos.duration` to get the duration of HTML5 video. This code gives the actual duration of Netflix and Youtube videos on chrome. On safari this works fine for Youtube but for Netflix videos it gives wrong duration. On inspecting the DOM of Netflix video on safari I observe the duration property of videos keeps on changing. Is there any way to get the exact duration of Netflix video on safari.

Comment: Depends if Netflix is using HTML video or something else.

Comment: Its using HTML5 video  https://help.netflix.com/en/node/22822